# codeigniter only inserting data as user 1

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I am trying to insert some data into MySQL database. however it only accepts user 1 insert which is the first user in the database table. how can I get it to insert all users no matter the user number.

Thank you for your time.

here is my insert code

```
       <?php

        class Mdl_chat extends CI_Model{

     function Mdl_chat(){

    parent::__construct();

     }

        function add_chat_message($chat_id, $user_id, $chat_text){
    $query_str = "INSERT INTO chat_message (chat_id, user_id, chat_text) VALUES(?,?,?)";
    $this->db->query($query_str, array($chat_id, $user_id, $chat_text));
     }


       function get_chat_messages($chat_id, $last_chat_message_id = 0){

    $query_str = "SELECT
    cm.chat_message_id,
    cm.user_id,
    cm.chat_text,
    DATE_FORMAT(cm.created_at, '%D of %M %Y at %H:%i:%s')as chat_message_timestamp,
    u.username,
    u.profile_image_url
    from chat_message cm
    right join user as u on cm.user_id = u.user_id
    WHERE cm.chat_id = ?
    and cm.chat_message_id > ?
    ORDER BY cm.chat_message_id asc";
    $result = $this->db->query($query_str, array($chat_id, $last_chat_message_id));

    return $result;

      }



      }


   below is my user model which I am using to pass the user id that is in session to the sql
   query in order to retrieve the right user against the chat message.

     <?php

    class Mdl_users extends CI_Model{



/*
*call to model class
*/

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}


/*
*get userid from email column
*/ 
function get_userID($email){
$this->session->set_userdata('user');
$this->db->where('email',$email);
$query = $this->db->get('user')->row_array(); // retrieves row in session.

return $query['user_id'];

}


    //get username
      function get_username($email){
       $this->db->where('email',$email);
       $query = $this->db->get('user')->row_array(); // retrieves only first-row.
     return $query['username'];
   }

       public function create_user()
    {
    $new_user_data = array(

        'Email'=> $this->input->post('email'),
        'Username'=> $this->input->post('username'),
        'Password'=> $this->input->post('password'),
    );

    $insert = $this->db->insert('user',$new_users_data);
    return  $this->db->insert_id();

      }


     }
```

Answer (score 0):

in your database table try to make chat_id as Primary Key and check the auto increment option On

Comment: yes auto increment is on maybe I should show my user model